# mod_rewrite: rewrite existing files to friendly links

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I went through a bunch of websites and tutorials yet can't find a solution. 
Following snippet works and http://example.com/page/pot return a pot.php content

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]*)$ $1.php?page=$1 [L]
```

I can't get it to work the other way around

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/page$ $1.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current approach will cause infinite looping since Apache re-injects rewritten URI back for further rule processing.

You need to use THE_REQUEST variable for that like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+page/[^.]+\.php\?page=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ page/%1? [R=302,L]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]*)/?$ $1.php?page=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Good Solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/page$ $1.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Comment: That doesn't work either I'm afraid
`RewriteEngine on`
`RewriteRule ^([^/]+),page$ $1.php?page=$1 [L]`
Anything but "/" as separator works